# Add Page Tab dialog no longer working

Tags: url, facebook-apps

I used to have my users add my app by clicking a link that was emailed to them, or by using the add page tab dialog. Both are described here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

As of Friday (3-Aug-2012) neither of these seem to be working. The user simply sees a page that says, "An error occurred. Please try again later." with no further explanation. Even clicking the example URL on the above mentioned page produces the same error. I get this error for any app, while signed on with any facebook profile.

Has anyone experienced this, and if so, do you know what needs to be changed so that it will work again?

Answer (score 0):

This commonly happens when your app is missing settings in the **Page Tab** section of the **Basic** (Page Tab URL, Secure Page Tab URL) settings.
It will also happen if your app has **Sandbox mode** enabled.

I've filed a ticket to get the example link on that documentation page corrected (thanks).

Comment: That isn't the problem, since apps that did work stopped, and as I said, it was for any app, including their example. Unlikely that all of my apps that did work suddenly had incorrect settings unless Facebook changed something and didn't document it.

Comment: I agree that's strange. I was just listing the common reasons; maybe it will be helpful for others in the future. Unfortunately, it wasn't the case for this particular situation. The FB example in that doc has been fixed. Let's see if others are seeing the same issue since Friday, Aug-3.

Comment: Hmm, if it's been fixed, perhaps I'll just be able to look at it and see what, if anything, they changed. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, FB didn't change anything that is visible for that example.  They changed the settings for the app that supports the example.

Comment: Actually, they did change the link. They changed it from:
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL to: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=188435367875530&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL

Comment: Actually, the page (and therefore the link & html) hasn't changed since 2012/05/30 15:08:52 US-PT.  Moreover, I talked to the person who owns app_id=188435367875530 to troubleshoot the issue on Aug-7. I offer this data to encourage all of us to look elsewhere for the cause of this error because the example in the doc is a red herring.